# Angularjs md-select not showing md-model

Tags: angularjs

I have two md-select dropdown boxes showing on my page and for some reason, I can get the value of one to display from $scope but not the other.

The working md-select looks like this and works fine:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <label for="">Units</label>                        
   <md-select style="margin:0px" name="units" ng-model="product.units" aria-label="select" required>
    <md-option value="kg">kg</md-option>
    <md-option value="g">g</md-option>
    <md-option value="mg">mg</md-option>
   </md-select>                       
  <span></span> 
</div>
```

The md-select that does not work looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Supplier</label>
   <md-select style="margin:0px" ng-model="product.compname" name="supplier" aria-label="select" >
     <md-option value="kg">kg</md-option>
     <md-option value="kg">mg</md-option>
    </md-select> 
     <span></span>
</div>
```

I have no idea why but when I replace "product.compname" with "product.units" it works fine. However when I try to replace it with other product data like "product.name" it doesn't work either.

UPDATE:

After a lot of good help I'm trying to setup the md-select like the docs but I'm still having issues. My scope for the two varialbes looks like this:

```
$scope.suppliers = data.data; 
$scope.selectedSupplier = [ $scope.suppliers[$scope.product.supplier] ];
```

In the console, both suppliers and selectedSupplier look fine. On the html page I have the following but it's still not working. I can see all the suppliers in the list but the page still loads with the dropdown box blank and no options selected. What do you think?

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedSupplier" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
 <md-option ng-value="supplier" ng-repeat="supplier in suppliers">{{ supplier.compname }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Are you declaring $scope.product in the beggining of your controller? And try declaring $scope.product.compname = "" just for testing..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Seem to be a step closer with the testing, but no solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at the Angular material demos?

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select

I am not sure why you want to have ng-value and ng-model both set to the value of product.compname?

The most common use case would be one of these:

```
<md-select ng-model="drinkSelected">
    <md-option value="water">Water</md-option>
    <md-option value="juice">Juice</md-option>
    <md-option value="milk">Milk</md-option>
    <md-option value="wine">Wine</md-option>
    <md-option value="mead">Mead</md-option>
</md-select>
```

or

```
<md-select ng-model="drinkSelected">
    <md-option ng-repeat="drink in drinks" value="{{drink}}">{{drink}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Note: I couldn't comment due to not enough reps so I have answered the question.

UPDATE:

Your update looks fine. Can you please share a trimmed down version of your code in plunker or codepen?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm working with the demo docs now to replicate your setup but still no luck. I'm editing the question now, hopefully you'll see something I'm missing!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are forgetting to add the 'ngMaterial' module to the list

```
var myApp = angular.module('microwaveGUI',['ngMaterial', 'ui.tree', 'angularResizable', 'ngMap', 'withLocals', 'ngRoute']);
```